# Tcl/Tk: How to create a progress bar with a status text inside?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I want to create a progress bar using Tcl/Tk >= 8.5 that does not only **show the progress in a graphical way but also the percentage of the progress as number (centered) within the progress bar** (e. g. "12 %").

I am thinking about overlaying the progress bar and a label transparently or one making the parent of the other widget but I could not figure out a solution.

Any ideas?

Here is a simple program frame:

```
proc Counter {} {
  for {set i 0} {$i < 100} {incr i} {
    puts "$i"
    after 25
    .pb configure -value $i
    update idletask
  }
}

ttk::progressbar .pb -orient horizontal -maximum 100 -length 400 -value 0
button .bt -text "Start counter" -command Counter
pack .pb
pack .bt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't. The standard platform rendering of progress bars doesn't support such a label.

***However,*** you can hack something together with `frame`s and `label`s (and clever use of `place`). I wrote [this page](http://people.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ezzcgudf/tcl/mwidx.html#progress) long ago which has links to code that does just that. It should still work, but it might not look how you really want: the standard for what these things should look like has changed a lot over the years.

[image]

<sup>I *hate* self-promotion, but I don't know of any other code that does this.</sup>

Comment: Really cool, it works. Now I am trying to understand the source code (a lot of new commands for me).

Comment: The tricky bits are how the widgets are stacked and placed with respect to each other; it's _very_ hacky. Also, it uses `option add` and that's downright obscure. (It was obscure even when I wrote it!) But not important for understanding how the code works; it's a lot like how you can ignore the CSS to start with when looking at a complicated webpage.